# Is it possible to combine using heavy weapons and light weapons in this way as a monk?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat, weapons, actions

I had the idea of a character with levels battle master 3 and  Kensei 8.

I want to mainly use my greatsword to attack. However, I had the idea of using a dagger as a kensei weapon to benefit from the +2 ac from time to time. In the future, I could use a venom dagger as well and combine different features, since you need 2 hands to use a greatsword but not carry it, and I can have an interaction as a part of my action.

Are the following scenarios possible?

Scenario A:

1. Attack with dagger
2. Sheath dagger as part of the action
3. Attack with greatsword

Scenario B:

- First turn:

  1. 2 attacks with greatsword
  2. Unsheath dagger as part of the action (after the attacks)
  3. Use agile parry as bonus action
- Second Turn:

  1. Use action to poison dagger
  2. Action surge
  3. Make 1 attack with dagger (while holding the greatsword on the other hand)
  4. Sheath dagger as part of the action
  5. Make 1 attack with the greatsword
  6. Flurry of blows as bonus action

Comment: Welcome to the rpg stack! You can take the [tour] as an introdution to the site. I did a substantial edit to hopefully improve the format of the post but feel free to [edit] it further or revert it completely if I made a mistake or there's something you don't like. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: It would have to be some potent poison. You're taking about giving up two attacks just to make one poisoned attack!

Answer (score 3):

## A is possible

Simply put, there is no reason why you shouldn't be able to sheathe the dagger between the attacks of the Attack action, nor any rule that the Extra Attack has to be taken using the same weapon. If you want to use a similar technique on your next turn, you can attack with the greatsword first, then unsheathe the dagger and attack with the dagger.

## B is not

**Agile parry** cannot be used as a bonus action:

> If you make an unarmed strike as part of the Attack action on your turn and are holding a kensei weapon, you can use it to defend yourself if it is a melee weapon. ...

You need to be holding your dagger (or another kensei weapon) and while making an unarmed strike as a part of your Attack action in order for the bonus to activate. If you use your Attack action to make two attacks with the greatsword, you have expended the Attack action without triggering **Agile parry**. However, you could attack once with the greatsword, unsheathe the dagger and perform an unarmed strike to gain the bonus, and follow it up with a bonus action unarmed strike attack from the *Martial arts* class feature.

The latter part, using one's Action surge to gain an additional action, and using it to attack with dagger, sheathe the dagger, attack with greatsword and use *Flurry of blows*, is legal.